# What is Revolutionary Monotheism?

Tags: israel

Can anyone help explain to me what this concept is? I'm aware of monotheism in the Bible but not Revolutionary Monotheism.

Thank you.

Comment: Who used the term and in what context?  What is the source? Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Thankyou. I understand your position and appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

As near as i can tell it is just the catchy title for one specific conference in 2007, and the [published proceedings for the same](https://www.eisenbrauns.org/books/titles/978-1-57506-199-3.html).

> In February, 2007, a conference entitled “Reconsidering the Concept of ‘Revolutionary Monotheism’” was convened on the campus of Princeton University. The meeting was unique in that it brought together scholars who were engaged in various disciplines of research, and though all were involved in the geographical area of the ancient Near East, everyone brought a different expertise to the question of how to approach the concept of the divine. What followed, in the course of two days, was an intense debate regarding the issue stated in the title of the conference; the dialogue was productive, and the papers—which were reworked in the wake of the conference and in accord with the interaction among the participants—are useful perspectives on the vexing topic of monotheism and the divine.

> The papers in the this volume are presented by John Baines (gods in New Kingdom/Third Intermediate period Egypt), Gonzalo Rubio (Mesopotamian pantheon), Francesca Rochberg (polytheistic cosmogony in Mesopotamia), Beate Pongratz-Leisten (astralization of gods in Mesopotamia), Peter Machinist (dying gods and cosmic restructuring), Mark S. Smith (cross-cultural recognition of divinity in Israel), Konrad Schmid (monotheism in the Priestly texts), John Collins (king and messiah as Son of God), and P. O. Skjærvø¸ (Zarathustra and monotheism).

Comment: Thank you. Monotheism is well researched. Revolutionary Monotheism is new to myself.    I think the general idea is that there was a monotheistic movement (from polytheism) in various religions around the time of the Assyrian empire, and this is when the concept of the God of Israel took hold. I believe the God of Israel's monotheism's characteristics are so unique (compared to polytheism)it may be revolutionary.